# Why does backend development need a separate server?

Tags: node.js, frontend, frameworks, backend

I am developing my own website. So far, I've used React for the frontend and Flask for the backend. I've been doing frontend development for a while now but I'm just starting to get into the backend.

From my limited understanding, frameworks like Flask and ExpressJS create their own servers and host data that the frontend can use. It seems to me that that they automatically create websites to host and receive data. In my website, I route the backend to do what I want and use fetch requests with POST and GET from the frontend to communicate.

Although it works, to me, it seems overly complex. Why does the backend need it's own server? It seems unnecessary to create a proxy for the frontend and fetch data. Why can a website not just run custom code in the background, why does it need a service like Flask or ExpressJS to run in the background for it? These backend frameworks run Python or NodeJS in the background, but wouldn't it be much simpler if the website itself could run Python or NodeJS in the background?

I also see that in frameworks like React, you can import things and use modules— like in NodeJS. While importing some modules works, the `require` keyword is not allowed and normal NodeJS code will not work. Therefore, the backend will not work. Why is this— why can't you just run backend code natively? Instead you have to go through fetch and specify headers to basically translate information from your frontend to your backend.

Forgive my amateur understanding of web development, but the frontend/backend system seems overly complex to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking back with a lot more experience, I think I can answer this question.

What confused me was that developers go through all the hassle of back-end libraries to write complex APIs, when the same code can be run in the front-end. It seemed like a very roundabout way to build websites.

To understand why developers do this, you have to have a fundamental understanding of the back-end and front-end, which are, at a primitive level, the same.

#### How responses work

In the web, people host URLs— addresses for servers. These URLs, when visited, send requests to a specified server. The server executes code according to its programming, and sends a response back. Web frameworks just allow developers to do this more efficiently and easily.

When you go to a URL and receive a response from the server, that response is the server's message, (usually) packaged by a framework. This means that everything from the entirety of Google, to unformatted JSON, is essentially plain text with some additional info (headers) that tells your browser how to handle the response.

#### Client and server code

To get back to what I was asking, the reason you can't just write back-end code in the front-end, is because when the front-end sends a response, it is running whats called client-side code, and this is often undesired. When front-end frameworks "package" a response, they take your code, and send a response some HTML according to your instructions.

Any and all programming logic needed, is run within the HTML using `script` tags. This is client-side code. Although you may not be using JavaScript, all front-end frameworks ultimately compile to JavaScript that runs in the browser.

The problem with client-side code though, is that your end-users (clients) shouldn't necessarily have access to server operations. If you are trying to say insert a document into your database, process a payment, or run any sort of sensitive code, doing so on the front-end would be unsafe (and often inefficient).

Instead, what you can do is run back-end (server-side) code. The same way that front-end frameworks take code you write and serve it to the world by "packaging" it, server-side code, is simply code that runs before (or alongside) the packaging.

When you send a request to a server, server-side code executes locally, and then sends a response based what the local code evaluates. This solves the problem of running sensitive code, because the code runs on the server (not the client) *before* the evaluation is returned to the user.

#### Why the back-end and front-end is (usually) separate

While both back-end and front-end libraries are just packaging systems, back-end libaries can importantly run server-side code. Back-end and front-end libaries are usually seperate simply because of conveinence (with frameworks like NextJS being the exception). Sending code as user-friendly HTML, often presents different challenges than sending it as plain text or JSON. Frameworks just make it easier to do what you need to do with each.

### TLDR

Frameworks *can* run code in the "background" (back-end), but they usually shouldn't for security and efficiency reasons.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the backend need it's own server?

Where will the client store data so that when you open the page again the data will still be there? You can use `localStorage` but this is locked to that particular browser. What if someone logs in on a different device or uses a different browser?

Where will the client get the application from in the first place? Your application needs to be packaged up in a form that can be easily downloaded, and it needs an address to be loaded from. This is all considered "back end" even if you're using a static hosting service like GitHub Pages.

There's a lot of reasons why a back-end exists and needs its own server. Any application with persistent state which is expected to work across different sessions needs *at least* one of these.